# Conditional Styling of Radio Buttons not working(VueJs)

Tags: css, vue.js

I am trying to make a quiz app. Where on clicking the option, there is an immediate feedback of whether it is the correct answer or not. I am trying to achieve this with CSS and conditional class styling in VueJS.

But the result is different. Let us say option 1, 2 and 3 are wrong answers and option 4 is correct answer. When I click at option 1 or option 2, option 3 is getting selected.

```
.gpquiz .incorrect input[type="radio"]:checked ~ label:before {
    content:'\274C';
    text-indent: .9em;
    color: white;
    background-color: maroon;
}

.gpquiz .incorrect input[type="radio"]:checked ~ label {
    background-color: #fff4f4;
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alosies/8qs78joq/1/)

Comment: it's not a CSS issue, as you can see it's working for less than a second when you check ... but i am sure VueJs is adding some event in order to change states when you check the answers, so you need to see what's happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues here. Firstly, with a radio list you need to bind `v-model` to one underlying variable so Vue selects the correct option, in your example you are binding your radio buttons to an array index, but you need to do:

```
<input type="radio" value="1" v-model="selected">
<input type="radio" value="2" v-model="selected">
```

The problem is that you have given each of your radio buttons a value of either `true` or `null` based on their `correct` value, so you need to set the value to something unique, such as `index`. Also, because you are going to be reusing this piece of code you should wrap it in it's own component and pass the question as a `prop` so:

```
Vue.component('question', {
  template: '#question',
  props: ['question', 'number'],
  methods: {
    hideOption: function() {
      this.disabled = true;
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      selected: ''
    }
  }
})
```

Then your markup would be (I've removed some properties for clarity):

```
<template id="question">
  <div>
    <h5>{{question.instruction}} {{selected}}</h5>
    <h5>{{number}}. {{question.text}}</h5>
    <ul >
      <li v-for="(option, optionindex) in question.options">
        <div :class="{correct: option['correct'],  incorrect: !option['correct']}">
          <input type="radio" @click="hideOption" :value="optionindex" :name="number" v-model="selected">
          <label>{{option.text}}</label>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

Then in you main Vue instance you can do:

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="col-sm-8 gpquiz">
    <question :question="question" :number="index+1" :key="index" v-for="(question, index) in questions"></question>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the JSFiddle for that: https://jsfiddle.net/8ocmun6s/

You now have a second problem, your user can select a correct or incorrect answer but your main Vue instance doesn't know anything about what was selected, to do that we need to `$emit` that event back to the parent and we can do that by using a `watcher` to watch our `selected` value and `$emit` the event when it changes:

```
  watch: {
    selected(answer) {
      let correct = this.question.options[answer].correct
      // Emit the question number and whether it was correct back to the parent
      this.$emit('user-selected', this.number, correct)
    }
  },
```

And, we can now listen to that on the component and trigger a method (in this case `selectAnswer`):

```
<question :question="question" :number="index+1" :key="index" @user-selected="selectAnswer" v-for="(question, index) in quiz.questions"></question>
```

Now we just need to add that method:

```
methods: {
  selectAnswer(number, correct) {
   // use $set here otherwise view won't detect the change
   this.$set(this.userResponses, number-1, correct)
  }
},
```

Now we have an array of true or false answers we can present the result, I'm just going to use a `computed`:

```
computed:{
  correctAnswers(){
    // Return the number of correct answers
    return this.userResponses.filter(x => x).length
  }
},
```

Now we can just show and hide that when the user submits the form, so we can add the following to methods:

```
submitAnswers() {
  this.submitted = true;
}
```

And also make sure you declare `submitted` in `data`, then you can bind that to the button and add the conditional to your markup, which ends up as:

```
<div id="app">
  <h1>{{quiz.title}}</h1>
  <hr>
  <div class="col-sm-8 gpquiz" v-if="!submitted">
    <question :question="question" :number="index+1" :key="index" @user-selected="selectAnswer" v-for="(question, index) in quiz.questions"></question>

    <button @click="submitAnswers">
      Submit
    </button>
  </div>
  <h4 v-else>
    You got {{correctAnswers}} out of {{userResponses.length}} Correct!
  </h4>
</div>
```

And here's the final JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fvk4L326/